# Swift UI: Dismiss the MainView and delete all model data after log out

Tags: xcode, swiftui

In the ContentView I have either the MainScreen or the SignInView displayed. When I logout it switches to the SignInView but of course does not delete the current data which is stored in the Models from the previous logged in user. Is there a way to dismiss this MainScreen and all of the data stored in the Models/ ViewModels so that the new logged in user has a fresh database and no conflicts occur. Thinking about this the MainScreen View itself should be "new" after signing in in the SignInView, MainScreen() gets called. I know there would be the manual way of clearing all data arrays but maybe there is a more convenient way.

> ```
>         if viewModel.signedIn {
>             MainScreen().onAppear{
>                     if let unwrappedUserID = self.viewModel.auth.currentUser?.uid{
>                         self.profileData.RetrieveUserData(unwrappedUserID: unwrappedUserID)  
>                     }
>             }
>         }
>         else{
>             // If no login can be found go to login
>             SignInView()
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Same as you set up something in `onAppear`, you can clean up that in `onDisappear` (obviously it wan't be done automatically), like:

```
    if viewModel.signedIn {
        MainScreen()
         .onAppear{
                if let unwrappedUserID = self.viewModel.auth.currentUser?.uid{
                    self.profileData.RetrieveUserData(unwrappedUserID: unwrappedUserID)  
                }
         }
         .onDisappear {
           // << make clean up here !!
         }
    }
```

Comment: No, `@StateObject` wrapper is read-only, so you'd rather need something like `profileData.cleanup()` or `profileData.reset()`

Comment: So these must be methods I have to create by myself which then clear the attributes in the classes.